# Symfony From CollectionType, добавить новый элемент в зависимости от выбора пользователя

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony5, symfony-form

дорогие друзья. Мне нужно динамически добавлять элемент в зависимости от выбора пользователя.
Итак, есть форма с CollectionType.
После рендринга формы, пользователь открывает модальное окно с типами модели которая связанна через параметр entry_type|CollectionType.
Я лишь додумался до того то в момент выбора типа отправлять всю форму и выбранный тип в контроллер  через POST запрос и добавить элемент как показано ниже

```
switch ($action) {
    case 'addBlock':
        $type = $request->get('link')['bock_type'];
        $type = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(BlockType::class)->find($type);
        $new_block = new Block(); 
        $new_block->setType($type);
        $link_page->addBlock($new_block);

        $form = $this->createForm(LinkType::class, $link_page);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return new JsonResponse(['view'=>$this->renderView('app/profile/prototype/blocks_form.html.twig',['form'=>$form->createView()])]);

        break;
}
```

Но возникла проблема из за строчки

```
  $form->handleRequest($request);
```

добавленный элемент не учитывается, а если убрать эту строчку вовсе, то добавится лишь 1 элемент в CollectionType.
Я понимаю что можно при каждом добавлении модели Block сохранять сущность, но это немного не то что мне нужно.

Подскажите дорогие обыватели как можно решить эту задачу, может вообще каким-то другим путем.

Comment: В документации же есть раздел о динамическом изменении формы в зависимости от выбора.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: И вправду, подумал что это не подойдет в моем случае. Ошибался.
Оставьте ответ, выберу его как решение вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации есть раздел о динамическом изменении формы в зависимости от выбора.

symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html